# Sum of same id in Array of object using php

Tags: php

I want to add given_points from both array of object and show in single array of object with the help of student_id bcoz in both array of object student_id is unique.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 91
            [given_points] => 8
            [bonus_points] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 91
            [given_points] => 6
            [bonus_points] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 95
            [given_points] => 9
            [bonus_points] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 95
            [given_points] => 9
            [bonus_points] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try looping the array? Can you show the code you tried? What is the expected result?

Comment: $newarray = array();
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
    foreach($ar as $k => $v)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($v, $newarray))
            $newarray[$v]['given_points'] = $newarray[$v]['given_points'] + $ar['given_points'];
        else if($k == 'student_id')
            $newarray[$v] = $ar;
    }
}

print_r($newarray);

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: do you have those array separated ?

Comment: @AmodKumar , check my answer , if you want to sum student_id and given_points .

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
 sum+=$array[$key]['given_points'];

}

echo $sum //prints sum
```

Comment: What if there is more than one student in the array?

Comment: You loop foreach but use as a for loop. `$array[$key]['given_points'];` is the same as `$value['given_points'];`

Comment: Above solution not working, plz recommend something else

Comment: Have array below
Array
( [0] => stdClass Object
        (  [student_id] => 91
            [given_points] => 8
            [bonus_points] => 2 )[1] => stdClass Object ( [student_id] => 91
            [given_points] => 6
            [bonus_points] => 1))
Array
( [0] => stdClass Object
        (  [student_id] => 95
            [given_points] => 9
            [bonus_points] => 1) [1] => stdClass Object( [student_id] => 95
            [given_points] => 9
            [bonus_points] => 1)
)
for student_id = 91, i have to show as a sum of given_points and also same for student_id = 95

Comment: plz check above problem and recommend some solution for same

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum_points = 0;
$sum_student_id=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($value->given_points))
     $sum_points += $value->given_points;
  if(isset($value->student_id))
     $sum_student_id += $value->student_id;
}
echo $sum_points;
echo $sum_student_id;
```

> since this is an  array of stdClass , use **->** instead of brackets 
>    **['']**

There is another way : *(PHP >= 5.5)*

```
$sum_points = array_sum(array_column($array, 'given_points'));
$sum_student_ids = array_sum(array_column($array, 'student_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    0 => ['student_id' => 91,
        'given_points' => 8,
        'bonus_points' => 2
    ],
    1 => ['student_id' => 91,
        'given_points' => 8,
        'bonus_points' => 2
    ],
    2 => ['student_id' => 92,
        'given_points' => 8,
        'bonus_points' => 2
    ],
    3 => ['student_id' => 93,
        'given_points' => 8,
        'bonus_points' => 2
    ]
];


foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (isset($newArray[$row['student_id']])) {
        $newArray[$row['student_id']] = $newArray[$row['student_id']] + $row['given_points'];
    } else {
        $newArray[$row['student_id']] = $row['given_points'];
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

You can try something like above code. Basically since the student_id is the unique identifier of your table and you want your logic implemented based on this then make it your new array key field.

The above code will work as many records as you have and the outputted array will look like:

```
Array
(
    [91] => 16
    [92] => 8
    [93] => 8
)
```

2 users with id 91 added, and the rest were unique users in separate array fields.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for reply
But above code  not working
plz recommend something else

Comment: It's not working cause i am using an array as an example and u are having objects. Just access your values like an object, that's minor change.